# How to stop regex at the end of line

Tags: regex, jscript

trying to figure out next case:
I have txt file with parameters

```
environment=trank
Browser=iexplore
id=1988
Url=www.google.com
maautomate=no
```

When I parse this txt file with regex pattern like

```
/environment=([^\s]+)/
```

I got "trankBrow" as result, or

```
/Url=([^\s]+)/
```

I got www.google.commaautomate=no

So why second parameters appended? And how to get "trank" only?

Comment: add `$` at the end of your regex

Comment: Perhaps, [`environment=([a-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lN7sP8/1)? This will limit matches to just lowercase letter sequences. It seems there is no whitespace between `trank` and `Browser`.

Comment: Nope, still the same

Comment: @ stribizhev
Problem when trying Url=([a-z]+)? it returns only "www"

Comment: Thx, guys, u are the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
environment=([^\\s]+)
```

You need to use this. `\s` in your case is escaping `s` and so the output is `trankBrow` because after that `s` is there.

Comment: can you explain every sign here?

Comment: @Kamrad this is ur regex....u just needed to escape s so that it becomes non space characters